# Изменение размеров окна в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Столкнулся с проблемой изменения размеров окна UWP.

Пробовал изменять размеры окна в разметке XAML с помощью свойств Height и Weight, результата не дало - содержимое окна сжимается в заданных размеров, а окно остается в тех же пропорциях.
Так же пробовал изменять в методе инициализации окна:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Height = 300, Width = 500 });
```

Аналогично, результатов не дало.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно изменить размеры окна.

Comment: [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888254/6766879), только имейте ввиду, что размеры задаются в "эффективных" пикселях

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде бы окно изменяется в размерах, но только есть две проблемы: через раз окно изменяется в размерах само по себе, а так же существует некая минимальная граница изменения размера. Попытка изменения свойств MinWidth/MinHeight не помогает

Comment: Ну в UWP само по себе понятие окна как бы отсутствует и вы не должны им явно управлять, система может вообще не дать вам менять размеры, так как, приложение может быть запущено на системе в планшетном режиме или на мобильной Win10. Возможно вам стоит использовать WPF или разработать несколько представлений с разной компоновкой элементов для разных устройств

Comment: А если, допустим, приложение будет использоваться только преимущественно в Windows 10, и одно из окон не должно быть больший размеров? В качестве примера могу привести окно регистрации в системе. Как можно выпутаться из данной ситуации?

Comment: Я бы использовал какой-нибудь `Flyout`/`Popup`/`ToolTip`. Там есть еще, вроде, диалоговые псевдоокна, но я не уверен, что они полностью кастомные

Comment: Ну и предложение разрабатывать WPF вместо UWP актуально

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду пробовать. Вопрос исчерпан

Comment: Можно просто отрисовывать Grid нужного размера поверх основного контента.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста конкретней? Вы имеете ввиду создать агрегацию Page?